# Midje tests with maven test

Tags: maven, clojure, midje

I am using Clojure maven plugin and I have written tests using both `clojure.test` and midje.

Clojure.test integrates well with maven and `mvn test` runs all tests, whereas midje tests are evaluated but not reported from `mvn test`. I found a [post on google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure-maven-plugin/lPYV7MODO0g) that was referring to enclose the facts in a `deftest` block. Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: Why don't you like that solution?

Comment: We wanted to keep things separated out as in use midje for a set ot tests and clojure.test for another set I was wondering if there is any solution for midje tests to be run from 'mvn test'